# Writing to a New or Existing Folder

Tags: python, operating-system

I have a Python function for writing a text file to a new or existing folder.  The issue is the first time I run the function, when the folder does not exist, I get a TypeError: Object of type 'NoneType' has no len().  The second time I run it, after the folder was created, it works fine.

```
import os

def save_string_to_folder(new_folder, string):
    folder_path = 'C:\Users\e6082493\Documents\Improve\Python\Scraping\Folder_%s' % (new_folder)
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        folder_path = os.makedirs(folder_path)
    join_path = os.path.join(folder_path, string)
    join_path_finish = open(join_path, "w")
    join_path_finish.close()


save_string_to_folder('new', 'TextFile.txt')
```

I would have thought my 'if' statement would correct for this error.  I cannot seem to figure out the step I am missing.  Thanks.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_2.py", line 12, in <module>
    save_string_to_folder('new', 'TextFile.txt')
  File "new_2.py", line 7, in save_string_to_folder
    join_path = os.path.join(folder_path, string)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 65, in join
result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
    if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
PS C:\Users\e6082493\Documents\ImproveBKFS\Python\Scraping>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the traceback

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I do not believe there is a module called .makedir(), maybe in a different library I do not know about?

Comment: No, both part of `os`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html). There are two methods; `makedir` and `makedirs`. You're using plural. I'm just not sure about the `NoneType` part, hence why I'm asking for a stack trace of the error rather than just a single line of it.

Comment: I think the answer you have been given is correct actually. The recursion goes down the path and makes each of the directories missing in sequence, the issue is that you try to assign this to `folder_path`.

Comment: Yes I see that assigning to folder_path does not work because of <class 'NoneType'> as shown by pmuntima, it does work if I assign a whole new name, or no assignment at all, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `os.makedirs` does not return anything. When you assign the return value of `os.makedirs` function call to the folder_path, it now contains `<class 'NoneType'>`. The following code should work as expected.

```
import os

def save_string_to_folder(new_folder, string):
    folder_path = 'C:\Users\e6082493\Documents\Improve\Python\Scraping\Folder_%s' % (new_folder)
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        os.makedirs(folder_path) # Removed the assignment
    join_path = os.path.join(folder_path, string)
    join_path_finish = open(join_path, "w")
    join_path_finish.close()


save_string_to_folder('new', 'TextFile.txt')
```

From the second time, the folder is already created, so it does not enter the if condition and remove the valid path in variable `folder_path`